# Running grafana behind apache2 reverse proxy

Tags: apache2, kibana, reverse-proxy, grafana

I need to run grafana and kibana on a same server while running behind Apache2 reverse proxy

I manage to succeed with kibana, but grafana cause me some problems; in fact I don't how how to run the sub path.

I want these two services to run like this : X.X.X.X/kibana and X.X.X.X/grafana.

Here is my apache2 config and my grafana settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://myipadress/kibana
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://myipadress:5601/
ProxyPassReverse / http://myipadress:5601/
</VirtualHost>


#--------------GRAFANA----------------------------
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://myipadress/grafana
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://myipadress:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://myipadress:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

For grafana :

```
protocol = http
http_port = 3000
domain = myipadress
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana
serve_from_sub_path = true
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong

Cheers

Comment: Can you expand where and what error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Hello after loosing too much time on it, I decided to change my reverse proxy and use NGINX.
I fact, there is a example of configuration in grafana's documentation, and I just added these lines

```
  location /kibana {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5601/kibana;
  }
```

And it just work for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Removing the last `/`from
`ProxyPass / http://myipadress:3000/`solved it for me. I can't explain why, but I hope this helps anyone who has the same problems.